# How to keep / save a specific Azure backup

Tags: azure, backup, azure-backup-vault

My daily backup policy for VM's keeps backups for 30 days.

Now I want to save a specific backup and keep it for a longer time. As a baseline for work.

Is this possible with Azure? How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you need to backup the VM  on demand. One of the ways this can be done is from the Azure Portal.

1. Navigate to the VM  which needs to be backed up. Under Operations section , select Backup menu.
2. Click Back up now.
3. It gives an option to specify a date till which you want(a custom retention period) to preserve your backup copy.

Comment: Is there also some documentation on how to restore a VM. I tried it once but I don't see any changes. Restore is reported successful but I don't see the files I expected to see. IMHO restore does not do anything